# Animating random tiled background

Tags: javascript, css

I am creating a website and I love the background effect on this site with the images animating in and out: http://www.6wunderkinder.com/en/#/welcome

I haven't put any code together yet. I know how to set the page up and make it responsive etc, but I am not sure in what direction to go for making the images randomly (it seems random) animate in and out. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Edit:** I would like to know how to pick the random element.

Comment: In the right direction in terms of the picking of random element or animation?

Comment: Picking random element.

Comment: It looks like it is all setup with CSS3 animations. Basically they have a few different delays setup, which are hard-coded as a class on each of the images. There is a bit of JS that picks a random image and adds a 'hide' class, which triggers the animation. The class can also be randomly removed to re-show it.

Comment: .oO( `var idx = Math.ceil(Math.random() * array.length); var theRandomElement = array[idx];` ... but i suspect the question asks for more ... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this - **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qYKdX/)**

**jQuery**

```
function randomFade() {

    var items = $('ul li');
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
    //console.log(random)

    items.eq(random).find("img").fadeOut("slow", function () {
        // call back here, either fade in a new image, or do something else
        alert("item faded out!");
    });

}

setInterval(function () {
    randomFade();
}, 3000);
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=1" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=2" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=3" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=4" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=5" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=6" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=7" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=8" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=9" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=10" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li { float:left; width:50px; height:50px; border:1px solid #000; margin:5px; list-style:none;}
```

**Edit:**

For the Callback, replace the `alert` with:

```
var $this = items.eq(random).find("img");
$this.attr("src", "http://placehold.it/50x50&text=new");
$(this).delay(300).fadeIn(300);
```

**Or**

create an initial array with a list of images you want to show, then you can pick a random item from that list and fade it in.

Comment: Why I love SO. Thanks very much, exactly what I need to start.

Comment: Yeah we love it. Asking what's "the one ingredient" for a cake and _getting a cake_ for free. Wonderful. :)